# TmxMapLoader to use packed tileset

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

In the old libgdx map api, they used to have

```
map = TiledLoader.createMap(Gdx.files.internal("maps/testmap.tmx"));
atlas = new TileAtlas(map, Gdx.files.internal("maps"));
tileMapRenderer = new TileMapRenderer(map, atlas, 8, 8);
```

However in the new libgdx the rule changes, to load a tilemap there is no longer needed to use map packer first. You can directly use the .tmx file with the tileset png. Something like following will work, and then call render.

```
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/testmap.tmx");
```

My question is the original tileselt.png that used to generate the .tmx file, it's size is not power of two. So I still have to either use Texture packer or a map packer to pack it for using.

I could not successfully associate the packed file with the .tmx;

Is there anyway to approach this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you target GLES 1.0, you will need power-of-two tilesets. Some devices might allow non-power-of-two with GLES 1.0, but that isn't guaranteed. With GLES 2.0 this restriction is lifted, but you still might get better performance out of power-of-two.

You can still use the TiledMapPacker-produced maps, you will just need to load the map with `AtlasTmxMapLoader` instead of `TmxMapLoader`.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at documentation. Looks like AtlasTmxMapLoader.loadMap is the only function that would be able to associate the tmx with the pack file. Is this the one that I should use?  What should I pass in for [XmlReader.Element root],    [com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.AtlasTmxMapLoader.AtlasResolver resolver], and [AtlasTmxMapLoader.AtlasTiledMapLoaderParameters parameter]?  Thank you so much!

Comment: If your map has the `atlas` property (as would be the case with the TiledMapPacker), you can just call the `load` method, passing in the path to your tmx file.

Comment: you mean the altas property should also be defined somewhere in the tmx file?   The TiledMapPacker is just standard [tileset.png + tileset packfile]. Where can I define the atlas property?

Comment: In the .tmx file, The property is <property name ="blended tiles" value="..."></property> <tileset><image source="tileset.png"/></tileset> should I change the image to atlas? or something similar?

Comment: Ah, yeah if you used the old tiled map packer I guess it didn't set the atlas property. Just add properties element to your map with a single property with the name being "atlas" and the value being the name of your pack file. Alternatively you could use the new tiled map packer to regenerate the atlas.

Comment: Major thanks for this, I didn't know about the AtlasTmxMapLoader. Saved me much time. +1

Answer (score 1):

They do not need to be power of two. If you have Problems with it like you get the power of two error set `Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);` inside of your MainClass.

You do not need the packer anymore so i think you cant associate the packer to the tmx file.

If you use the `TmxMapLoader` the tilesets need to be inside of the same folder of the `.tmx`file. 
If they are inside of an different directory you need to configure the source path inside of the `.tmx` file. here is an Example:

```
<tileset firstgid="257" name="mountain" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <image source="mountain.png" width="512" height="512"/>
</tileset>
```

is the regular output of Tiled. If the Tileset is inside of for example config it you need to change it like this:

```
<tileset firstgid="257" name="mountain" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <image source="config/mountain.png" width="512" height="512"/>
</tileset>
```

But it still need to be a subfolder of the path where the tmx file is.

Regards hope that may helps.

Comment: Thanks, does it affect the graphic performance if the image size is not power of two?

Comment: not that i know of but i dont realy know whats behind that stuff.